# Що таке "так" у фразеологізмі "з ма́ком і з та́ком"?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Фразеологізм "з ма́ком і з та́ком" означає "і краще, і гірше; всіляко, по-різному".

Цікавить, що означає в цьому контексті слово так. Я спробував пошукати в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/tak) і з усіх визначень, можливо, може підійти наступне:

> 7. розм. Указує на відсутність того, про що йшла мова раніше. У мого батька було три стодоли: в одній був мак, друга була так, а в третій
>      миша з розуму зійшла, що їжі не знайшла (Українські народні прислів'я
>      та приказки, 1963, 68); Кому смак, а кому й так (Українські народні
>      прислів'я та приказки, 1963, 68).

Але тут ідеться про прислівник, а в фразеологізмі без сумніву вжито іменник. Більше мені нічого знайти не вдалося.

Answer (score 4):

На жаль, "чіткої" відповіді в словниках знайди не вдалося, але в [Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/en/njt.html) натрапив на переклад словосполучення "Пироги с нетом" і його переклад "пироги з **таком**" або ж "**нізчимні** пироги". Також знайшов вислів про пироги в творі ["Дар Евтодеї" Докія Гуменна](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=14293&page=3):

> Що воно за пироги з таком? Треба й собі спробувати! Купив і я — а в
>   пиріжку нема ніякої начинки.

Тобто, я можу зробити висновок, що "з таком" - це "з нічим", відповідно "так" - це "ніщо". І швидше воно якось пов'язане із тим прислівником з СУМу (вислів "з таком" поширений у народі), визначення якого я навів у запитанні.